# Does VB.NET have functionality similar to TSQL's "IN"?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In TSQL..

```
IF MyVal IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 14) BEGIN ... END
```

Is there a way to do this in VB.NET?

Is it possible to check for the existence of an integer in a set of integers **inline**?

Such as:

```
If MyVal in (1, 2, 3, 4, 14) Then ... End If
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays are an implementation of `IEnumerable` so with the `System.Linq` import a shorthand version of Tim Schmelter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9951829/112196) would be:

```
{1,2,3,4,14}.Contains(MyVal)
```

Arrays also have an [explicit implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336401.aspx) of `IList.Contains`, so without LINQ a perhaps less elegant alternative is:

```
DirectCast({1,2,3,4,14}, IList).Contains(MyVal)
```

Answer (score 3):

For example [List.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) Method

```
Dim MyVal = 4
Dim MyValues = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.ToList

MyValues.Contains(MyVal)
```

Or [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx):

```
MyValues.Sort()
Dim contains = MyValues.BinarySearch(MyVal) > -1
```

Or [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

```
MyValues.Any(Function(item)item=MyVal)
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. I did not know you could create and populate a list inline like this.